# Access Table Schemas or Execute a command via a Datagrip plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin, datagrip

Is it possible to invoke the "execute" command for a selected text via a DataGrip plugin?

And if not (or regardless actually), is it possible to access the table definitions of the current schema?

Answer (score 1):

> "execute" command for a selected text via a DataGrip plugin

Selected text is executed on Cmd+Enter automatically. If no text is selected, DataGrip suggests you options what to execute (whole file, this statement, etc)

> access the table definitions of the current schema

Cmd+F1 will show table's structure in the console:
[image]